# Coldfusion and Twitter JSON

Tags: json, serialization, twitter, coldfusion

I am running the following code I found on the internet to grab a load of Tweets with a particular hashtag:

```
<cfset consumerKey = "MY_CONSUMER_KEY">
<cfset consumerSecret = "MY_CONSUMER_SECRET">
<cfset bearerToken = ToBase64(consumerKey & ":" & consumerSecret)>
<cfset authorization = "Basic " & bearerToken>

<cfhttp url="https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token" method="post" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#authorization#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="grant_type=client_credentials">
</cfhttp>

<cfset bearerTokenResponse = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)>
<cfset authorization2 = "Bearer " & bearerTokenResponse.access_token>

<cfhttp url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" method="get" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#authorization2#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="q" value="%23ColdFusion">
</cfhttp>
```

Obviously I have put in my own keys in the consumerkey & consumersecret variables.

```
{"statuses":[{"created_at":"Tue May 17 16:32:17 +0000 2016","id":732609696109080577,"id_str":"732609696109080577","text":"Well done Team Konstruct! \n\n#konstruct\n#pvd\n#suncity\n#dunhill https:\/\/t.co\/yRUPIXmQ6t","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"konstruct","indices":[28,38]},{"text":"pvd","indices":[39,43]},{"text":"suncity","indices":[44,52]},{"text":"dunhill","indices":[53,61]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/yRUPIXmQ6t","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/3kyQTnmLe","display_url":"fb.me\/3kyQTnmLe","indices":[62,85]}]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":238145671,"id_str":"238145671","name":"Vincent Viljoen","screen_name":"konstructdesign","location":"Brackenfell, Cape Town","description":"I design and build exhibition stands. I love it when my clients win awards for their stands and their brands stand out because of my creativity...","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/soGTwPlFhi","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/soGTwPlFhi","expanded_url":"http:\/\/konstruct.co.za","display_url":"konstruct.co.za","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":589,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":18,"created_at":"Fri Jan 14 13:36:08 +0000 2011","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Pretoria","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":1863,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1465748472\/VW_1_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1465748472\/VW_1_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/238145671\/1369226061","profile_link_color":"009999","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"}],"search_metadata":{"completed_in":0.015,"max_id":732609696109080577,"max_id_str":"732609696109080577","query":"%2523konstruct","refresh_url":"?since_id=732609696109080577&q=%2523konstruct&include_entities=1","count":15,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}}
```

I have searched endlessly for weeks in the way that I can use this to display in a legible way. So for instance suppose I wanted to output on the page, the actual tweet(s), the handle of who posted the tweet and the date - how!!! It is driving me mad as I am sure I did something like this before but can't remember how!

Many thanks in advance.

J

Comment: So what code have you tried to display the info? What is the issue you have? Hard to help without knowing what you've tried so far. Only hint I can give you based on what you've shown is to use `DeserializeJSON()` to covert the response to a CF data-type.

Comment: Hi there - I have tried lots of things! The ;latest being: <cfscript>
   record = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent);
   writeOutput(record.statuses.id);
   
 </cfscript>. Basically if more then one tweet comes back how do I separate them out and display them in a legible way and just display handle, tweet and possibly date? I can't work out how to drill down.

Comment: *I have tried lots of things! The latest being...* It is preferable to include at least some of what you have actually tried in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37408886/edit).  We realize it will not be perfectly "working" code, but ... providing a starting point makes it easier for folks to assist and/or identify the issues you may be having :)

Comment: What happened is that after something didn't work I ended up deleting it - and I have tried so much that I have now forgotten what it was that I tried :) - but point well made - I need to keep better records!! Cheers J

Answer (score 1):

Answering you comment, you can loop through an array in CFSCRIPT using a for loop.

```
// from / to loop
for (i=1;i LTE ArrayLen(array);i=i+1) {
    WriteOutput(array[i]);
}
```

OR

```
// for .. in loop
for (elem in array) {
    WriteOutput(elem);
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
response = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent);
for (status in response.statuses) {
    WriteOutput(status.id);
}
```

I would of course run the text portion of the struct through a function(s) to replace the new lines with break tags and make the urls anchor tags.

Comment: When I run what you suggest I get the following: Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array. - J

Comment: Is this for a single tweet? You could wrap the for loop in an isArray() test and only loop if the resulting variable is an array. Otherwise use it as a struct. If I were doing this project, I would use AngularJS to grab the JSON from your ColdFusion template (Simply cfoutput the JSON at the bottom of the page) and then use the ngRepeat directive to output the tweets. I would also add a cfcontent with a reset immediately before the cfoutput.

Comment: (Edit) The above works fine with a small tweak. The response is a structure, not an array. The array is contained in the "statuses" key of the response structure.  You need to loop through the "statuses" element, not the parent structure . ie `for (status in response.statuses) { ..... }`. @RusselMadere - Hope you do not mind, but I modified the above with the working code. If you do not like it, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Outstanding. I will never be upset with a tweak or correction.

Answer (score 0):

I've tackled something vaguely similar before. The answer I got was to put that JSON into an array and loop through it.

First thing is first, we need our JSON to work with us. I used [this online validator and formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Made things tremendously easy to read.

I got rid of the final element, `search_metadata`, because it was acting as another primary scope for all my neat variables and we can't have that. To remove it automatically using ColdFusion you may want to make use of the `SpanExcluding` function.

So you were left with this:

```
[{"created_at":"Tue May 17 16:32:17 +0000 2016","id":732609696109080577,"id_str":"732609696109080577","text":"Well done Team Konstruct! \n\n#konstruct\n#pvd\n#suncity\n#dunhill https:\/\/t.co\/yRUPIXmQ6t","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"konstruct","indices":[28,38]},{"text":"pvd","indices":[39,43]},{"text":"suncity","indices":[44,52]},{"text":"dunhill","indices":[53,61]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/yRUPIXmQ6t","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/3kyQTnmLe","display_url":"fb.me\/3kyQTnmLe","indices":[62,85]}]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":238145671,"id_str":"238145671","name":"Vincent Viljoen","screen_name":"konstructdesign","location":"Brackenfell, Cape Town","description":"I design and build exhibition stands. I love it when my clients win awards for their stands and their brands stand out because of my creativity...","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/soGTwPlFhi","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/soGTwPlFhi","expanded_url":"http:\/\/konstruct.co.za","display_url":"konstruct.co.za","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":589,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":18,"created_at":"Fri Jan 14 13:36:08 +0000 2011","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Pretoria","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":1863,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1465748472\/VW_1_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1465748472\/VW_1_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/238145671\/1369226061","profile_link_color":"009999","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"}]
```

I'm not sure how you personally want to handle this string but I used a `cfsavecontent` to turn it into a variable called `Tweets`.

Then:

```
<cfset ArrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(Tweets)>
```

Now that it's in a list I can loop through it and grab all the information I want. Example:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#ArrayOfStructs#" index="i">
#i.created_at# <br/>
#i.id_str#
#i.text# <br/>
#i.user.name# <br/>
#i.user.screen_name# <br/>
#i.user.url# <br/>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

You can grab the code for Embedding Tweets straight from Twitter, then fill in the username and status number and all that good stuff on a webpage, which is exactly what I did!

[image]

This should work for 1 Tweet or 1 Million.

Does this work for you? I'm using ColdFusion 11.

Edit: As long as you are expecting the exact same format every time, you can parse out the `search_metadata` element with string functions. I'm not exactly sure how you'd go about it but I threw this together just now:

```
<!---Replace the beginning of the search_metadata element with a unique character--->
<cfset Tweets2 = replace(Tweets,',"search_metadata',"|")>

<!---Use SpanExcluding function to eliminate everything past the unique character.--->
<cfset Tweets3 = SpanExcluding(Tweets2, '|')>
```

You'd still have to manually add a `}` to the very end but that's academic. You wind up with the same string I did and should be able to loop through it.

Comment: Using the span excluding function I end up with the output just being ({ - and that's it :) - J

Comment: @JanSolo Edited in a little more. SpanExcluding is a weird kid.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and now the closing string ends with }]} and has no "search_metadata" - but when running the loop I get the error: "Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array" - cheers

Comment: @JanSolo you'll also have to get rid of the `{"statuses":` text at the beginning.

Comment: @TRose - You should not need to remove `search_metadata` as it is a separate key.  Just loop through the `ArrayOfStructs.statuses` array.

Comment: @Leigh I was actually unaware you could scope it like that. Cheers. JSON is an Achilles Heel of mine.

Comment: (Edit) @TRose - You are welcome. Since the base JSON string represents a structure,  when deserialized you can use the standard dot notation syntax to access specific keys, just like with any other structure. BTW, feel free to use it above if you want, so the syntax is more visible.